# Retrieve data using for loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question about using `foreach` loops in Ruby.

I want to display documents and  am using a `foreach` loop in order to display these documents. It returns an error with the `i` variable inside of `data["response"]["docs"][i]["topic"]` which is a JSON string I am iterating over.

I do not understand why that is. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

If I simply do `data["response"]["docs"][0]["topic"]` it works fine but not with the `i`. Why is that?

```
<%
(0..10).each do |i|
%>
<%= i %> <br/>
<%= data["response"]["docs"][i]["topic"] %> 
<%
end
%>
```

Comment: Rather than `(0..10)` consider using `n.times` where `n` is the number of times you want to loop. It's much more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is, how many items are there in `data["response"]["docs"]`? Are there exactly 11? Either way I would use the following code instead:

```
<% data["response"]["docs"].each_with_index do |item, index| %>
<%= index %> 
<br/>
<%= item["topic"] %> 
<% end %>
```

This iterates over the `data["response"]["docs"]` no matter how many there are (whether is is 1 doc or 20 docs) and stores the value in the variable named `item`. The [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) function gives you the index as well, stored in `index`, so you can display it later. If you only want the first 11 use:

```
<% data["response"]["docs"].first(11).each_with_index do |item, index| %>
```

This will grab a maximum of 11 doc items.

Comment: It consists of hundreds of documents, but I would only like to show the first 10 for starters and this works like a charm! I didn't know you can create the loop like this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what might be going wrong because you haven't posted the error, but if you're using a 10-element array, you want to do:

`(0..9).each do |i|`

With 0-based indexes, you should only use the range from 0-9, rather than 0-10.  You may be getting an error because you're trying to access an element that isn't there (i.e. at index 10).

Even better is:

```
<% data["response"]["docs"].each do |document| %>
<%= document["topic"] %>
<% end %>
```

or if you need to print the index:

```
<% data["response"]["docs"].each_with_index do |document, index| %>
<%= index %> <br/>
<%= document["topic"] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's preferable to _not_ use `...`. The 3-dot version is harder to read and is unknown to a lot of developers, leading to the possibility of bugs being injected during maintenance. It's better/idiomatic to use the 2-dot version, `..` with the trailing number being reduced by 1.

Comment: Interesting, I'll start doing that instead. Thanks Tin Man.
Answer has been edited.

Comment: Consider this also: It's easier to understand if you do `10.times do |i|` than it is `(0..9).each do |i|`. `i` will still start at 0 and count to 9, but it's more obvious the code loops 10 times.